# Uploading my second app to the app store? What should i do?

Tags: app-store-connect, profile

The first time i uploaded an app to the app store i followed a youtube tutorial. Now i want to upload my second app. I have a lot of trouble understanding the process to upload an app. I've create a Provisioning profile, A certificate and a Distribution profile for my first app, am i supposed to use those again? Do i need to create a new provisioning profile, a new certificate and a new distribution profile? It's really confusing since i've been coding for less then 2 months.
Some step-by-step information would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process is not as complicated as it seems

- You need one developer certificate for testing and one distribution certificate for deployment (ad hoc or AppStore). If you have a valid certificate (given that you submitted an app already), then make sure you have it in your keychain (with the private key).
- For a new app, you need to create a new appID. Remember that it should match the bundle identifier in your Xcode project.
- With the distribution certificate and the appID, you can create a new distribution provisioning profile that needs to be downloaded to your machine. And should be used for the code signing in Xcode.

So, short answer. Use you current (valid) distribution certificate, add a new appID (matching your bundle identifier) to create a new Distribution Provisioning Profile. Use the profile to code signe your project.

Good luck... enrique

Comment: That was really simple to understand, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

1. Definitely you need another provisioning profile connected to new APP ID for your second app
2. You dont need a new certificate though you need separate Appstore distribution provision profile.
3. Before creation of provision profile, you need to create APP ID.
4. After new APP ID you need to create new provision profile, you would be asked for select distribution certificate and you can select previous one there and also would be asked for APP ID and there you need to select your second app id (not older one).

Please check [Apple Distribution Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SubmittingYourApp/SubmittingYourApp.html). It has clear instruction to do so.

And you can also checkout [this tutorial](http://support.brightcove.com/en/app-cloud/docs/step-step-guide-publishing-apple-app-store-using-mac). It may help you.